# Function with an asymptote at y=-1 and y=1

Tags: functions, asymptotics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm looking for a function that has two asymptotes parallel to the x-axis. Preferably it should also only cross the x-axis at (0,0) and be built without using any trigonometric functions. Mind you, if that's not possible then so be it. However, that is my preference.

The purpose of this is that when the function is placed into the floor function and (manipulated a little) it will generate a function that is 0 at 0, 1 whenever the input is positive and -1 when the input is negative. Such a curve is the best bet I can come up with towards guessing a means to build such a construct.

I think I have seen the function somewhere at some point or a variation. I just cannot remember what it was.

Thank you

-The Great Duck

(Also, while I suppose it is probably obvious (can't place it in floor), no piece wise please)

Comment: Hint: Have you seen the graph of the arctangent?

Comment: The thing that makes it hard is that it cannot be a rational function.

Comment: If a rational function has horizontal asymptote in one direction, then it has the *same* asymptote in the other direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be creative with this and make up your own funtions. For example consider,

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x & \quad -1\leq x \leq 1 \\
            1 & \quad x \geq 1\\
            -1 & \quad x \leq 1
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: This is a function will all the prescribed notions you mentioned in your question. It's even more simple to understand. Its the identity up to $[\pm1,\pm1]$ and trivially satisfies the definition for horizontal asymptote.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: I don't want to argue. You should really try to give constructive responses and not be rude to users trying to help you. Most of us are ph.d student in mathematics, postdocs or professors. It is not my intention to lead you astray. I think your understand of functions (maps) is a bit loose.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck You do realize that every function can be written as a piecewise function, right? That a piecewise function is not somehow "less" of a function than any other one? To call the answer stupid or condescending or smart aleck is ridiculous, and you should carefully reconsider your engagement here.

Answer (score 5):

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

It should be apparent that this works because leading coefficient test provides asymptotes for $y=\pm 1$, and plugging in $0$ for $x$ yields $0$.

---

Edit: I found another one if you prefer it:

$$f(x)=\frac{1-e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}$$

Comment: @TheGreatDuck My pleasure.